# Offloading long blocking calls to separate threads using System.Observable

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I want to execute a blocking method into separate threads. To illustrate the situation, I created this example:

```
int LongBlockingCall(int n)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return n + 1;
}

var observable = Observable
.Range(0, 10)
    .SelectMany(n => 
        Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Return(LongBlockingCall(n), NewThreadScheduler.Default)));
    
var results = await observable.ToList();
```

I expected this to run in ~1 second, but it takes ~10 seconds instead.
A new thread should be spawned for each call, because I'm specifying `NewThreadScheduler.Default`, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace this line:

```
Observable.Return(LongBlockingCall(n), NewThreadScheduler.Default)
```

...with this:

```
Observable.Start(() => LongBlockingCall(n), NewThreadScheduler.Default)
```

The [`Observable.Return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211637(v=vs.103)) just returns a value. It's not aware how this value is produced. In order to invoke an action on a specific scheduler, you need the [`Observable.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211971(v=vs.103)) method.

Comment: And the OP can also drop the `Defer`.

Comment: @Enigmativity true, because the `SelectMany` does not limit the concurrency. But if you switch later to `Select`+`Merge(maxConcurrent)`, the `Defer` would be needed. Or if later you add a `Where` filter after the `SelectMany`. Having the `Defer` there offers peace of mind, at the cost of a minuscule overhead.